# How to install MySQL 8 from source on Ubuntu 22 to have multiple data directories for multiple server instances?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL Server 8 from this source distribution:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server

I want to be able to initialize multiple data directories and run multiple MySQL servers which are independent from each other on my system for testing purposes.

I tried to follow the instructions here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing-source-distribution.html

But after multiple attempts, I couldn't get it to work.
I hit walls such as:

- The installation was successful, but there is no mysqld binary in the bin directory (there are, however, 40 binaries, including many that have a mysql prefix, but not mysqld)
- Trying to copy mysqld from apt install gives errors such as "Ignoring user changes to '' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

Note: I want to be able to install for a user of my choice which is not the user mysql.

- [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Can't find error-message file
- [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /srv/mysql/files/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

What would be a step by step process of installing MySQL Server 8 and creating two data directories, lets say at /tmp/mysqldata1 and /tmp/mysqldata2, for the user "testuser"?

What I tried is:

- apt install all dependencies listed at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-installation-prerequisites.html
- download boost 77

wget https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.77.0/source/boost_1_77_0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf boost_1_77_0.tar.bz2

- run cmake to create make files

cmake ./mysql-server/ -DWITH_BOOST=/path/to/boost_1_77_0 -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/prefix -DWITH_DEBUG=1

- build

make -j VERBOSE=1

- install

make install DESTDIR="/path/to/mysql/install"

- try to initialize data dir

?/mysqld? --initialize-insecure --user=testuser --basedir=/path/to/mysql/install/prefix --datadir=/tmp/mysqldata1

But this didn't work so I'm lost from here.

Help?

Comment: This is probably better achieved with containers as in Docker or Kubernetes.